# Appending ngBindHtml function using .attr in link function not working

Tags: angularjs, ng-bind-html

A am attempting to attach the `ngBindHtml` directive in an application within a link function of a directive.  The module in which the directive is located injects `ngSanitize` like such:

```
 angular.module('ui.bootstrap.contextMenu', ['ngSanitize'])
    .directive('contextMenu', cm);
```

where `cm` is the directive function.  The link function looks like:

```
var link = function ($scope, element, attrs) {
        element.on('contextmenu', function (event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            $scope.$apply(function () {
                event.preventDefault();
                var options = $scope.$eval(attrs.contextMenu);
                var model = $scope.$eval(attrs.model);
                if (options instanceof Array) {
                    if (options.length === 0) {
                        return;
                    }
                    renderContextMenu($scope, event, options, model);
                } else {
                    throw '"' + attrs.contextMenu + '" not an array';
                }
            });
        });
    };
```

where `renderContextMenu` sketches out the html that will be attached to the body of the page.  Within this function I have the following lines of code:

```
$div.attr('ng-bind-html', text);
$a.append($div);
```

which should produce something that looks like:

```
<a><div ng-bind-html="the text"></div></a>
```

and it does.  The problem is that the text is not actually displayed.  Does anyone have any thoughts on this?

Comment: you are trying to manipulate the DOM directly, thats not the angular-way to do things. Thats jQuery. The thing you try to do should be sorted with a binding. For instance by creating a directive for the small submodule and pass the text to it.

Comment: This comment I don't understand.  From the documentation on directives: *At a high level, directives are markers on a DOM element (such as an attribute, element name, comment or CSS class) that tell AngularJS's HTML compiler ($compile) to attach a specified behavior to that DOM element (e.g. via event listeners), or even to transform the DOM element and its children.*  And in this [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive), there is even a section entitled **Creating a Directive that Manipulates the DOM**.  The above code uses the jqLite supplied by the Angular framework.

Comment: I believe that this has to do with the how the link function is called relative to the production of the DOM.

Comment: DOM-manipulation is supported, but it is considered bad practice by many. Just like controllers are by many seen on as "do not use". Using directives (with a directive-controller) often creates cleaner code and also makes it much easier to upgrade to ng2 later.

The example they use is a perfect situation where you would just use a binding rather than manipulating the DOM.

Comment: So...it seems that you are not interested in answering the question but lecturing about the "angular-way".  I am still not following what you are trying to say, so I will try to explain and maybe you can provide some constructive insight.  I have a directive that that will produce a context menu when the user right-clicks on a particular element.  I want the menu to 1) appear where the right click event happened and 2) display user provided names attached to user defined functionality.  The context menu may contain nested menus.  Go.

Comment: And this is a branch of an existing repo that likely will contain a controller specific to the directive (although I have *never* heard any developer say controllers are "do not use" - including [John Papa](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide) and [Todd Moto](https://github.com/toddmotto/angular-styleguide)).  And, both of those refs point out that **DOM manipulation belongs in the directives** ([here](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#directives) and [here](https://github.com/toddmotto/angular-styleguide#directives)).

Answer (score 1):

I think the "angular-y" way of doing this is to put the html code for the context menu that you're hoping to bind directly into the template, and just hide/show it as appropriate: only show it if a valid contextmenu event occurs and has options.length > 0.

Comment: Thought of this, use ``ng-if`` and ``ng-repeat`` directives; but this runs into a nest of other issues...  I will investigate this further.  That being said, the html will still have to be decorated using ``angular.element()`` calls as we have to position things appropriately...Also running into an issue here with nested scopes as this is a directive that may be nested in another directive...

Comment: Sigh...don't think I can shoe horn this into a more angularly way...the nested scope thing really creates some hassle....

Comment: if you need information between multiple directives, either pass it through with bindings. Or if it could be seen as "global" information, you could store it in a service and just inject the service into the directives. But it is hard to come up with a good solution when you only ask directly about what you want to do - rather than explaining the problem you want to solve.

Comment: Why can't you use https://github.com/Templarian/ui.bootstrap.contextMenu @cirrusio?

Comment: I am...this is what I am trying to augment.  The context menu provided is very basic.  Won't allow for 1) nested menus (I have built this in now) and 2) html in the tags (this is what this is trying to address).

Comment: @Etse - I am not trying to pass information between directives.  I am simply trying to render html rather than raw text.  Simple as that.